# PiTFT - How do I have access to the PuTTy terminal while the GUI is running?

Tags: gui, pitft

I am connected to the RPi via SSH with PuTTy

To start the GUI on the PiTFT I run the following command on the PuTTy terminal:

```
FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb1 startx -- -dpi 60
```

Now, I want to use the PuTTy terminal to run python scripts but can't because the GUI proccess is running on the terminal.

How do I have access to the PuTTy terminal while the GUI is running?

Comment: Try adding `&` with a space after the command (`startx -- -dpi 60 &`).

Comment: I wish it worked, but it didn't :/

Comment: As in X (the GUI server) doesn't run properly?  This is rather odd as [it works for me](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/36968/5538) using `ssh` and an HDMI output.  If you are saying the command doesn't return, you typed it wrong or need to hit enter a couple of times to get the prompt back.  I don't use PuTTy but I don't think that should matter as it's the shell on the remote machine, not the terminal emulator, which is responsible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `screen`
It allows you to run commands (eg `startx`) in virtual terminal and then deattach from it and use PuTTY normally.

To install it use these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install screen
```

and then to start new session use

```
screen -S qwerty
```

you can use any command there and then press `ctrl-a` and `d` to deattach from session.
Processes running inside the `screen` will not be terminated even if you disconnect from ssh.

If you want to get back to `screen` use this:

```
screen -r qwerty
```